# A basis $B$ for a topological space $X$ is a ring of sets iff $X\in B$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space with basis $B$, and suppose that $B$ has the following properties:

1. $B$ consists of compact and dually compact$^\ast$ subsets.
2. For every triple $U, V, W\in B$, we have $(U\cap W)\cup (V\cap W)\in B$.
3. For every irreducible, basic saturated subset $Y\subseteq X$, there exists a unique $x\in X$ such that $$Y=\bigcap \{U_i\in B\,|\, x\in U_i\}\,.$$

I suspect that property (3) is not important for this proof, but I wanted to provide full context.

I would like to prove

> $X\in B$ if and only if $B$ is a ring of sets$^{\ast\ast}$.

One direction is quite simple: ($\Longrightarrow$) Suppose $X\in B$ and take $U, V\in B$. Then, by property (2),  $(U\cap V)\cup (U\cap V)=U\cap V\in B$ and $U\cup V=(U\cap X)\cup (V\cap X)\in B$.

The other direction I don't see. Here are some other things I *do* know:

(a) If $X\in B$, then $\{Y\subseteq X\,|\, Y^c\in B\}$ is a bounded distributive lattice (under intersection and union).

(b) If $\{Y\subseteq X\,|\, Y^c\in B\}$ is a bounded distributive lattice, then $B$ is a ring of sets.

(c) $B$ is a ring of sets if and only if $B$ is the set of all compact and open subsets of $X$.

Any help is appreciated!!

---

$^\ast$ A subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ is called *dually compact* if, for any family $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}\subseteq B$ such that $\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i\subseteq Y$, there exists a finite subfamily $\{U_1,\ldots, U_n\}$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i\subseteq Y$.

$^{\ast\ast}$ There are, evidently, a few definitions for "ring of sets." What I mean here is a collection of sets closed under finite intersection and finite union.

Comment: What does saturated mean in this context?

Comment: A subset $Y\subseteq X$ is *basic saturated* if $Y=\bigcap \{ U\in B\,|\, Y\subseteq U\}$.